# Convert join query to hibernate criteriaQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an entity as follows:

```
class entity {
    Long id,
    String createdBy,
    String status,
    Date lastModified
}
```

I want to create a Hibernate criteria query for the following SQL:

```
select a.id, a.createdBy, a.status 
from entity a 
    join ( select status, max(lastModified) lastModifiedOn 
           from entity 
           where status in ('A','B','C') 
           group by status) b on a.lastModified = b.lastModifiedOn and a.status = b.status;
```

How do I do that? What would be the criteria query? Should I create a 'sub criteria' query within a criteria query?